# PC starts (fans, lights), reboots, then hangs - motherboard damage?

Tags: boot, motherboard

I'm experiencing some pretty weird issues with a machine I'm setting up for a friend.

So first off this is a pretty old computer, I'd estimate around 10 years. It was working fine, but the OS was damaged and I used a live Linux CD to backup the files before I reinstall. Up until then all was OK, but then I've used the reset switch and the computer went berserk. When I start it, fans spin and LEDs light up, but after a few seconds it resets (dies for 2-3 seconds then starts back) and again, the fans spin and I can see the LEDs, but the machine is stuck - no POST, no HDD read, no output to the monitor, nothing (though I should note that even when it was working properly, there wasn't a POST beep).

**Could this mean the motherboard has been damaged somehow? Is there something for me to try?**

Comment: you could pull the battery out for 10 mins as a starter; then check everything is properly seated. Some mobo's, btw, don't have a beeper, though they usually have the header for one. I always carry a portable one, soldered to a header plug.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yup, that helped. Thanks, I was starting to get nervous :P If you put this in an answer I'll be able to accept.

Comment: Happy to oblige :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pull the battery out for 10 mins as a starter; then check everything is properly seated.

Some mobo's, btw, don't have a beeper, though they usually have the header for one. I always carry a portable one, soldered to a header plug.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the reset wire that is attached to the motherboard.  It's possible the reset switch is stuck in the engaged position forcing the system to continually cycle.

As well, unplug any USB devices or peripherals that you can to identify the device that may be causing the hanging, this includes CD's or DVD's that may be in a ROM tray and what not.

Take the system down to it's most minimal components to identify root cause.

Comment: Tetsujin's answer has solved the problem, but nonetheless thanks for your input.